# Android localhost: "Unknown error when fetching script." for Firebase Messaging ServiceWorker

Tags: android, angular, firebase-cloud-messaging, ionic4, service-worker

I am working on a web app with Ionic Angular framework that should be able to send across messages between the app served via the browser and its Android version. I am using Firebase Cloud Messaging, because my app otherwise uses Firebase already.

I followed this tutorial https://medium.com/@david.dalbusco/add-web-push-notifications-to-your-ionic-pwa-358f6ec53c6f, and also went through a recent follow-up of the post by the same author https://itnext.io/follow-up-web-push-notifications-and-pwa-in-2020-54d27fbc829a.

When testing locally on Firefox and Chrome, everything works as expected. Messages can be sent off and received.

The problem comes when I try to achieve the same on my Android test device. The ServiceWorker fails to register.  The SW script ("firebase-messaging-sw.js") is placed in the `src` web root. I tediously went through all instructions, so also my `angular.json` file contains a reference with

```
"assets":
  [...
    "src/firebase-messaging-sw.js"
  ]
```

When running my app as debug package on Android, and connecting it to Chrome DevTools , the device inspection prints out following error:

`TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://localhost/') with script ('https://localhost/firebase-messaging-sw.js'): An unknown error occurred when fetching the script.`

But when I enter the given path https://localhost/firebase-messenging-sw.js in the address bar of the DevTools window, the file is found and its content is displayed.

The exact same problem happens when using `http`.

Now for Android, I added already the lines `<preference name="Scheme" value="https" />` and `<preference name="ResolveServiceWorkerRequests" value="true" />` to the `config.xml`. But as you can see, it doesn't help.

I went through the Firebase documentation, triple-checked the given guidelines and searched here on StackOverflow. There are similar references regarding the ServiceWorker returning 404, but none is related to the problem on Android.

Have I overlooked something Android-specific to make the ServiceWorker work from localhost on the device?

Comment: Can you access that script on browser with the link "https://localhost/firebase-messaging-sw.js"  ?  Maybe during registration, the script is run and  an exception might have been thrown leading to this error.

Comment: @AntiqTech Yes, the file is found and the contents are shown in the browser. Note that the script works in Chrome and Firefox, but not on the Android device.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that you are trying to access `localhost` on another device, try to replace it by actual server ip, https://dev.to/jha/how-to-test-ionic-react-pwa-on-an-actual-device-while-developing-you-should-36m